# Playstore open source unofficial API

Tags: android, oauth, gmail

I was in search of an API which would help me get the details pertaining to different applications from playstore. After much googling and going through many solutions already given at SO, I decided to go for [Android Market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) though this API has few drawbacks.

I am mainly focusing on getting the reviews pertaining to an application - the major drawback here while I use this API is that, I do not get the reviewer name, app version, device and many more valuable information I need.

I have made enough of research to find any alternate methods are there to fetch this information, but to no avail.

During the research, [Appmonsta](http://appmonsta.com/dashboard/api-documentation/#app-reviews) api came to my notice, which claim to provide almost all the details available in the playstore, including username, device, app version etc.

I am sure they would not be maintaining a database which would not be a practical solution, as the market information is prone to change every second. And I am also quite sure, google would not be providing any update to them alone.

Since I am in need of such an API, I am curious to know, what would be the mechanism/technique they use or one should use, such that the whole playstore information  is available to them alone - atleast the complete details pertaining to a review.

Any help, comments, guidance in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's no official API so whatever you use you shall expect problems - if not today then maybe tomorrow, when Google change a thing in the store. But anyway, you may take a look at the Andlytics sources: https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics - maybe it'd suffice for your needs

Comment: thanks for the reply, though Andlytics is about fetching the information related to my applications alone in playstore; whereas my requirement is to fetch info for any app. Still, curious as to how Appmonsta accomplished the same!!

Answer (score 1):

> I am sure they would not be maintaining a database which would not be a practical solution, as the market information is prone to change every second.

If I were writing such a web API, I *would* in fact maintain a database and use it as a cache. New hits for a particular app page would potentially refresh the cache. The information would be obtained by [scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) the web page.

Answer (score 0):

The [WhereDat API](http://wheredatapp.com/developers/) searches the Android Play Store. It lets you find apps, using full-string search queries. It also supports auto-complete use-cases by using prefix-string search. The lookup API lets you get data about apps using their package as the key.